# Angular2 bootstrap error: Error: No ExceptionHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, systemjs

I have a problem with running angular 2 application. During call of

```
import { PlatformRef } from '@angular/core/src/application_ref';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './components2/app.module';


const platform: PlatformRef = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I have this error:
[image]

This is weird error, because BrowserModule is included:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core"
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is indeed weird. The only mistake I see in your code is missing semicolon `import { NgModule } from "@angular/core"; <-- this one`, but I'm not sure that's causing this mistake.

Comment: nope, semicolon is not something causing this problem ) but thanks

Comment: I've never done the type reference on the platform before, have you tried removing that?  Just doing: `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for comments and help. The problem was that in other file I had dependency to 'q-io/fs' package. Removing that, angular started without any additional manipulations.

Comment: I am getting the same error. After importing references to mat-automcomplete to the program. How do we find for dependency errors in my program

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your main.ts file with below code.

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

> **Note:** Use latest [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create your project.

Hope that helps!